# Instagram API Subscription endpoint asks for access token even though it is provided

Tags: node.js, instagram, instagram-api

I am sending a POST request to the Instagram API subscriptions endpoint to add a user subscription, but am getting the error:

`error: StatusCodeError: 400 -`
`{"meta":`
`{"code":400,`
`"error_type":"OAuthParameterException",`
`"error_message":"Missing client_id or access_token URL parameter."}}`

I have provided both the `client_id` and the `access_token` in my request.

Here is the request code.

```
let access_token = user[0].access_token
let options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/`,
        body: {
          access_token: access_token,
          client_id: instaConfig.client_id,
          client_secret: instaConfig.client_secret,
          object: 'user',
          aspect: 'media',
          verify_token: 'myVerifyToken',
          callback_url: `${callback_url}`
        },
        headers: {
          'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
        },
        // Automatically parses the JSON string in the response
        json: true
      }
// rp = require('request-promise')
      rp(options)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log('subscriptions response: ' + util.inspect(response, { showHidden: true, depth: null }))
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log('error: ' + err)
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't read from body. It needs to be passed from query param or headers.

Comment: I am now getting the error message: 

```error_message":"Invalid format for \"callback_url\". URL must start with \"http://\" or \"https://\""}}```

Comment: This url does not seem to be a valid url:          callback_url: `${callback_url}`